# Enabled encryption option for AWS RDS.How to test is data encrypted in Aws Rds?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created a Rds in aws by enabling encryption option. I need some background how this encryption works and test is it encrypting.

Answer (score 2):

The encryption is on the disk volumes that your data is stored on. Just like enabling encryption on EBS volumes of EC2 instances. There's really no way for you to test that it is actually encrypted.